# Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-provider

I am trying to open view with details about event when user tap on push notification message.
My problem it is I guess that I don't have a context in my firebaseBackgroundHandler function but I am not sure about this.

There is any solution to pass context to this handler?

```
Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {

    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

  
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print(message.notification!.body);
    

    Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context,
        listen: false)
        .show();
  }
```

and in initState I am calling `setupInteractedMessage`

```
void initState() {
    setupInteractedMessage();
}
```

I have initialized this provider in MutliProvider inside build method of this class:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ControllerProvider>(
          create: (context) => ControllerProvider(),
        )
```

When I launch this code I am getting this error:

```
E/flutter (13082): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ControllerProvider> above this MainNavigator Widget
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082): This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
E/flutter (13082): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082): - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
E/flutter (13082):   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
E/flutter (13082):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
E/flutter (13082): 
E/flutter (13082):   Make sure that MainNavigator is under your MultiProvider/Provider<ControllerProvider>.
E/flutter (13082):   This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, I wanted to display a `SnackBar` when the user clicked on a message that opened the app, which also needs a context. So I saved the `context` of my home widget to a sort-of global variable when the home widget was built and used that context.

Comment: I created variable ```late BuildContext bContext```, then inside build method ```bContext = context```, and change ```Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false).show();``` to ```Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(bContext, listen: false).show();```
but still same error

Comment: And are you sure that there is the `ControllerProvider` above this `bContext` in your widget tree? Try to check it with  Widget Inspector.

Comment: ```@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bContext = context;
    
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ControllerProvider>(
          create: (context) => ControllerProvider(),
        )```

This is my build method

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that this `bContext` is the building context where you define the `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Flutter needs to climb up the widget tree to find a provider, so you need a context that is below this widget.

Comment: Now I get ```Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value``` pointed at ```Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false).show();``` line.

Comment: Ok, I found out, I just need ```bContext = context``` in two places because of if statements. Now it's working, thank u so much.